# Generating trigonometric sums

Tags: trigonometry, infinite-loop

How can one generate *all*  cosine polynomials with $\pm1$ coefficient of following form:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\pm\cos kt.$$

I tried DO loop but couldn't  get all of them as clearly cannot exhaust $2^n$ possible cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
n = 10;
basis = Table[Cos[k t], {k, 0, n}];
Tuples[{-1, 1}, n + 1].basis
```